# Re-rendering KMLLayer in google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Having issues with a mapping application I am building. When a kml layer is rendered on the map and then removed, and another layer is added it does not appear on the map until the map is panned slightly.

Workflow

1. Load google map
2. Load KML Layer
3. Call to PHP page to generate new KML
4. Layer Original layer is removed

   kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                                   url: KML,
                                   preserveViewport: true
                               });
5. new KML layer is applied to map with following call

   kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                                   url: KML,
                                   preserveViewport: true
                               });

For some reason after step 5 I will not see the new kml layer rendered on the map unless I move the map ever so slightly. Has anyone seen this behavior?

I apologize for this question. Had a brain fart and forgot to call 
kml.setMap(map);

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for this question. Had a brain fart and forgot to call kml.setMap(map);